# Sum in sub query with group by

Tags: mysql, sql

Table name is User

```
id| name |daily_salary | expense | days
 1   A     $100            $50        5
 1   B     $50             $30        5
 1   C     $200            $50        5
 1   C     $100            $50        3
 2   D     $200            $50        2
 3   E     $200            $50        1
```

I would like to have expense/(daily salary*days).

From the table, ID is usually grouped.

But if there are same names, id and name should be grouped.

For example, when id is 1 and name is C, $50/{($200*5)+($100*3)}.

So it should be

```
id  | name  | value
1      A      $50/$500
1      B      $30/$250
1      C      $50/$1500
2      D      $50/$400
3      E      $50/$200
```

Here is the query that I have tried.

```
select id, name, (select expense/sum(daily_salary*days) from user group by name)
from user
group by id
```

The error message says the subquery should return more than one row.

Is there a way to fix this or implement it properly?

Comment: What if the expense is different on rows for the same name? If it can't be different, your table isn't properly normalized.

Comment: *For example, when id is 1 and name is C, $50/{($200*5)+($100*5)}.* Why 5 days for both source records, not 3 days for $100 daily_salary? What if expences in such records differs?

Comment: @Akina sorry for making you confused. It should be 3 not 5. I fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id, name, MAX(expense)/SUM(daily_salary * days)
FROM user
GROUP BY id, name
```

I use `MAX(expense)` to get a single `expense` value from the group.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I am wondering if I use MAX to get a single expense. Does SUM(daily_salary * days) add all elements having the same name? For example, when id is 1 and name is C, SUM(daily_salary * days) should be {($200*5)+($100*3)}. Because I am confused with how MAX works in this case.

Comment: They both work the same, it's the MAX and SUM for the id,name combination.